# Bluemix Account Pending

Tags: ibm-cloud

While I was trying to open the db service "Db2 Warehouse on Cloud" which I created it about 1 years before(It was called dashDB while I created it),I got the  message "Your account is pending.Please wait up to 24 hours for email confirmation of your account. Also, check your spam folder. If you still have not received your email confirmation, contact Bluemix Support to get help."
I have waited for 24 hours but the confirmation mail still don't come...
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Something for the IBM support

Comment: Sure,the problem is that my DB is still can be used but I can't access the management tool now.

Comment: My assumption is that when you created the service a year ago, you were using a trial account that expired after 30 days. Is that the case? When you attempt to log into Bluemix, do you see an option to have the email resent by any chance? This question is not technical programming question, which is likely why other people have down-voted it. In the future, this type of question is better for dW Answers: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/

Comment: I use the dedicated version as a IBM employee(of course it's a trial account but it won't expire),I don't think it's the same case as you say.

Comment: Thank you anyway,I will close this question.(Now I know this kind question should not be asked here but why there is a button "POST TO STACK OVERFLOW" in bluemix support?)

Comment: @RC.T We are aware of that issue and hope to have it addressed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Well..the service via bluemix seems to be inaccessible,but I can still access it using below URL.
https://dashdb-entry-yp-dal09-10.services.dal.bluemix.net